# What specific features/functionality will we gain of we go from TFS to GitHub?

Tags: github, tfs

I am not asking for opinions here. So please, nothing about a certain approach or use is better.

We are considering switching from TFS to GitHub (the other alternative is go to VisualStudio Online, with the TFS backend). What functionality do we gain from going to GitHub?

I ask because I haven't found anything. With TFS you can easily pull everything down for offline work (for some reason a lot of people claim you can't while with GitHub you can).

The only part of the system we care about is:

1. Check files out/in.
2. Merge changes.
3. Branching for each version. So main branches to 1.0, 2.0, ... 15.0. We generally are working in the last 3 main branches (13.0 bug fixes only, 14.0 add small features, 15.0 major new features) and it needs to carry bug fixes from 13.0 -> main -> 14.0 -> main -> 15.0.
4. Continuous integration. We're primarily C# and typescript/javascript. What I want here is on each check in, it compiles everything, runs all unit tests and emails if anything failed. If that is all running on a check in, the next run waits until the present one completes (or it can abort the present one and start over).

For the above very specific requirements, and just those requirements, what features/functionality will we gain if we switch to GitHub?

Comment: You certainly lose a lot: Project management/planning, build, release, manual testing. TFS is a lot more than just a source control platform. That said, this question will almost certainly get closed as "too broad".

Comment: @DanielMann - I was so careful to make sure it wouldn't get closed for being opinion, I forgot to define it closely enough to not be too broad. Thanks for the advice - that's what I'm seeing too.

Comment: Ok, I made it much more specific, which is not only a good idea in general, but helpful for us too as we only care about the 4 items above.

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of local workspaces, I see no specific advantage to switching to git if you are using tfs in any case.

Comment: TFS 2013 provides Git as a source control option and 2013.4 (and VSO) provide Pull Requests. I only see loss of functionality...

Comment: The thing that GitHub supports that TFS/VSO does not is OSS and Wiki support.

Comment: @MrHinsh - What is OSS (I assume not the WWII Office of Strategic Services)?

Comment: :) Open Source Software - There is no anonymous access to TFS